# Charging li-ion 72V with solar MPPT controller

Tags: lithium-ion, solar-cell, mppt, electric-vehicle

I have an EV 72V li-ion battery with given charger (peaks at 11 A).

My MPPT solar charger is designed among other types for li-ion up to 96V ie 12/24/36/48/60/72/84/96V settable at 72 V. 50 A max.

Given the amps will vary depending on sunshine it will provide the correct volts but limit the amps based on available sun. (Between 0.0 A to 11 A). And has all the features to vary the amps based on charge state, (float etc). and user defined max of, in my case 11 A.

Given that from time to time the input amps may fall short of the amps a wall unit may provide, my question is this.

Can I use this controller to charge my EV battery pack safely? It has all the protections etc. Essentially the amps may, from time to time, fall short of the 11 A (I'm sure the wall unit too varies amps likewise, based on charge state, averaging around 6 A, lets say.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that should work fine.

Just one caveat: Li-ion ion cells degrade while connected to a charger that keeps them at the full voltage. Either shut off the charger when the battery is full. Otherwise, you may want to reduce the max voltage from the charger to the equivalent of 3.4 V / cell for LFP cells or 4.0 V for LCO/NMC cells.